# When is it neater to use VECTOR representations vs INTEGERs?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

In the comment thread on an answer to this question: [Wrong outputs in VHDL entity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/27792/763) it was stated:

> "With integers you don't have control or access to the internal logic representation in the FPGA, while SLV lets you do tricks like utilizing the carry chain efficiently"

So, in what circumstances have you found it neater to code using a *vector of bits* representation than using *integer* s in order to access the internal representation? And what advantages did you **measure** (in terms of chip area, clock frequency, delay, or otherwise.)?

Comment: I think it's something hard to measure, since apparently it's just a matter of control over low-level implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written the code suggested by two other posters in both `vector` and `integer` form, taking care to have both versions operate in as similar way as possible.

I compared the results in simulation and then synthesised using Synplify Pro targetting Xilinx Spartan 6.  Code samples below are pasted from working code, so you should be able to use them with your favourite synthesiser and see if it behaves the same.

---

## Downcounters

Firstly, the downcounter, as suggested by David Kessner:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity downcounter is
    generic (top : integer);
    port (clk, reset, enable : in  std_logic; 
         tick   : out std_logic);
end entity downcounter;
```

### Vector architecture:

```
architecture vec of downcounter is
begin
    count: process (clk) is
        variable c : unsigned(32 downto 0);  -- don't inadvertently not allocate enough bits here... eg if "integer" becomes 64 bits wide
    begin  -- process count
        if rising_edge(clk) then  
            tick <= '0';
            if reset = '1' then
                c := to_unsigned(top-1, c'length);
            elsif enable = '1' then
                if c(c'high) = '1' then
                    tick <= '1';
                    c := to_unsigned(top-1, c'length);
                else
                    c := c - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process count;
end architecture vec;
```

### Integer architecture

```
architecture int of downcounter is
begin
    count: process (clk) is
        variable c : integer;
    begin  -- process count
        if rising_edge(clk) then  
            tick <= '0';
            if reset = '1' then
                c := top-1;
            elsif enable = '1' then
                if c < 0 then
                    tick <= '1';
                    c := top-1;
                else
                    c := c - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process count;
end architecture int;
```

### Results

Code-wise, the integer one seems preferable to me as it avoid the `to_unsigned()` calls. Otherwise, not much to choose.

Running it through Synplify Pro with `top := 16#7fff_fffe#` produces **66 LUTs** for the `vector` version and **64 LUTs** for the
`integer` version.  Both versions make much use of the carry-chain.  Both report clock speeds in excess of **280MHz**.  The synthesiser is quite capable of establishing good use of the carry chain - I verified visually with the RTL viewer that similar logic is produced with both.  Obviously an up-counter with comparator will be bigger, but that'd be the same with both integers and vectors again.

---

## Dividing by 2**n counters

Suggested by ajs410:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity clkdiv is
    port (clk, reset : in     std_logic;
        clk_2, clk_4, clk_8, clk_16  : buffer std_logic);
end entity clkdiv;
```

### Vector architecture

```
architecture vec of clkdiv is

begin  -- architecture a1

    process (clk) is
        variable count : unsigned(4 downto 0);
    begin  -- process
        if rising_edge(clk) then  
            if reset = '1' then
                count  := (others => '0');
            else
                count := count + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
        clk_2 <= count(0);
        clk_4 <= count(1);
        clk_8 <= count(2);
        clk_16 <= count(3);
    end process;

end architecture vec;
```

### Integer architecture

You have to jump through some hoops to avoid just using `to_unsigned` and then picking bits off which would clearly produce the same effect as above:

```
architecture int of clkdiv is
begin
    process (clk) is
        variable count : integer := 0;
    begin  -- process
        if rising_edge(clk) then  
            if reset = '1' then
                count  := 0;
                clk_2  <= '0';
                clk_4  <= '0';
                clk_8  <= '0';
                clk_16 <= '0';
            else
                if count < 15 then
                    count := count + 1;
                else
                    count := 0;
                end if;
                clk_2 <= not clk_2;
                for c4 in 0 to 7 loop
                    if count = 2*c4+1 then
                        clk_4 <= not clk_4;
                    end if;
                end loop; 
                for c8 in 0 to 3 loop
                    if count = 4*c8+1 then
                        clk_8 <= not clk_8;
                    end if;
                end loop; 
                for c16 in 0 to 1 loop
                    if count = 8*c16+1 then
                        clk_16 <= not clk_16;
                    end if;
                end loop; 
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture int;
```

### Results

Code-wise, in this case, the `vector` version is clearly better!

In terms of synthesis results, for this small example, the integer version (as ajs410 predicted) does produce 3 extra LUTs as part
of the comparators, I was too optimistic about the synthesiser, although it is working with an awfully obfuscated piece of code!

---

## Other uses

Vectors are a clear win when you want arithmetic to wrap-around (counters can be done as a single line even):

```
vec <= vec + 1 when rising_edge(clk);
```

vs

```
if int < int'high then 
   int := int + 1;
else
   int := 0;
end if;
```

although at least it's clear from that code that the author intended a wrap around.

---

Something I've not used in real-code, but pondered:

The "naturally-wrapping" feature can also be utilised for "computing through overflows". When you know that the output of a chain of additions/subtractions and multiplications is bounded, you don't have to store the high bits of the intermediate calculations as (in 2-s complement) it'll come out "in the wash" by the time you get to the output.  I'm told that this paper contains a proof of this, but it looked a bit dense for me to make a quick assessment! [Theory of Computer Addition and Overflows - H.L. Garner](http://search3.computer.org/csdl/trans/tc/1978/04/01675101-abs.html)

Using `integer`s in this situation would cause simulation errors when they wrapped, even though we know they'll unwrap in the end.

---

And as Philippe pointed out, when you need a number bigger than 2**31 you have no choice but to use vectors.

Comment: In the second code block you have `variable c : unsigned(32 downto 0);`...isn't `c` a 33 bit variable then?

Comment: @clabacchio : yes, that allows access to the 'carry-bit' to see the wrap-around.

Answer (score 6):

When writing VHDL, I highly recommend using std_logic_vector (slv) instead of integer (int) for **SIGNALS**.  (On the other hand, using int for generics, some constants, and some variables can be highly useful.)  Simply put, if you declare a signal of type int, or have to specify a range for an integer then you're probably doing something wrong.

The problem with int is that the VHDL programmer has no idea what the internal logic representation of the int is, and so we cannot take advantage of it.  For example, if I define an int of range 1 to 10 I have no idea how the compiler encodes those values.  Hopefully it would be encoded as 4 bits, but we don't know much beyond that.  If you could probe the signals inside the FPGA it might be encoded as "0001" to "1010", or encoded as "0000" to "1001".  It's also possible that it is encoded in a way that makes absolutely no sense to us humans.

Instead we should just use slv instead of int, because then we have control over the encoding and also have direct access to the individual bits.  Having direct access is important, as you'll see later.

We could just cast an int to slv whenever we need access to the individual bits, but that gets really messy, very fast.  That's like getting the worst of both worlds instead of the best of both worlds.  You're code will be difficult for the compiler to optimize, and almost impossible for you to read.  I don't recommend this.

So, as I said, with slv you have control over the bit encodings and direct access to the bits.  So what can you do with this?  I'll show you a couple of examples.  Let's say that you need to output a pulse once every 4,294,000,000 clocks.  Here's how you would do this with int:

```
signal count :integer range 0 to 4293999999;  -- a 32 bit integer

process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if count = 4293999999 then  -- The important line!
      count <= 0;
      pulse <= '1';
    else
      count <= count + 1;
      pulse <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

And the same code using slv:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
signal count :std_logic_vector (32 downto 0);  -- a 33 bit integer, one extra bit!

process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if count(count'high)='1' then   -- The important line!
      count <= std_logic_vector(4293999999-1,count'length);
      pulse <= '1';
    else
      count <= count - 1;
      pulse <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Most of this code is identical between int and slv, at least in the sense of the size and speed of the resulting logic.  Of course one is counting up and the other is counting down, but that's not important for this example.

The difference is in "the important line".

With the int example, this is going to result in a 32-input comparator.  With 4-Input LUT's that the Xilinx Spartan-3 uses, this is going to require 11 LUTs and 3 levels of logic.  Some compilers might convert this into a subtraction which will use the carry chain and span the equivalent of 32 LUT's but might run faster than 3 levels of logic.

With the slv example, there is no 32-bit comparison so it's "zero LUT's, zero levels of logic".  The only penalty is that our counter is one extra bit.  Because the additional timing for this extra bit of counter is all in the carry chain, there is "almost zero" additional timing delay.

Of course this is an extreme example, as most people wouldn't be using a 32-bit counter in this way.  It does apply to smaller counters, but the difference will be less dramatic although still significant.

This is only one example of how to utilize slv over int to get faster timing.  There are many other ways to utilize slv-- it only takes some imagination.

**Update:  Added stuff to address Martin Thompson's comments about using int with "if (count-1) < 0"**

(Note:  I assume you meant "if count<0", since that would make it more equivalent to my slv version and remove the need for that extra subtraction.)

Under some circumstances this might generate the intended logic implementation but it is not guaranteed to work all of the time.  It will depend on your code and how your compiler encodes the int value.

Depending on your compiler, and how you specify the range of your int, it is entirely possible that an int value of zero does not encode to a bit vector of "0000...0000" when it makes it into the FPGA logic.  For your variation to work, it must encode to "0000...0000".

For example, let's say you define an int to have a range of -5 to +5.  You are expecting a value of 0 to be encoded into 4 bits like "0000", and +5 as "0101" and -5 as "1011".  This is the typical twos-complement encoding scheme.

But don't assume that the compiler is going to use twos-complement.  Although unusual, ones-complement could result in "better" logic.  Or, the compiler could use a sort of "biased" encoding where -5 is encoded as "0000", 0 as "0101", and +5 as "1010".

If the encoding of the int is "correct" then the compiler will likely infer what to do with the carry bit.  But if it is incorrect then the resulting logic will be horrible.

It's possible that using an int in this way could result in reasonable logic size and speed, but it is not a guarantee.  Switching to a different compiler (XST to Synopsis for example), or going to an different FPGA architecture could cause the exact wrong thing to happen.

Unsigned/Signed vs. slv is yet another debate.  You can thank the U.S. Government committee for giving us so many options in VHDL.  :)  I use slv because that is the standard for interfacing between modules and cores.  Other than that, and some other cases in simulations, I don't think there is a huge benefit to using slv over signed/unsigned.  I'm also not sure if signed/unsigned support tri-stated signals.

Comment: David, those code fragments are not equivalent. One counts up from zero to an arbitrary number (with an expensive comparison operator); the other counts down to zero from an arbitrary number. You can write both algorithms with either integers or vectors, and you will get bad results when counting towards an arbitrary number and good results counting towards zero.

Note that software engineers would _also_ count down to zero if they need to squeeze out a little more performance out of a hot loop.

Comment: @Philippe They are equivalent in that they both will output a pulse every arbitrary number of clocks.  You could reverse the counting direction of the int example and the logic/speed improvements of the slv version would still apply.

Comment: Like Philippe, I'm not convinced that this is a valid comparison.  If the integer example counted down and used `if (count-1) < 0` I'd think the synthesiser will infer the carry out bit and produce much the same circuit as your slv example.  Also, shouldn't we be using the `unsigned` type these days :)

Comment: @MartinThompson  I added stuff to my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that if one uses vectors, the synthesis tools would be expected to use the particular representation specified, whether it is more or less efficient than some other representation, whereas if one uses integers the tool would be free to use whatever representation it sees fit, theoretically allowing it to pick the optimum one but in practice more likely failing to exploit possible optimizations?

Comment: Also, with regard to the question of whether it's better to use count-to-N-reset-to-zero or count-to-zero-reset-to-N, different silicon technologies may favor each approach, especially when N is constant.  Even when N is variable, some silicon technologies may still favor the comparison.

Comment: @supercat Yes.  SLV puts the optimization ball into the engineers court and int TAKES IT AWAY from the eng.  At the moment, and foreseeable future, an eng is better at optimization because the eng can make design choices that are beyond what the compiler can do (like switch from counting up to down).  Certainly with LUT based FPGA's with dedicated carry chains it is better to "count-to-minus-one-reset-to-N-minus-two", although there almost certainly are silicon architectures that I'm not familiar with that would favor a different approach.

Comment: @DavidKessner: One change which has occurred in the programming industry, and I wouldn't be surprised if silicon development follows, is that a lot of code is used on a variety of machines, such that an optimization for one would be a pessimization for another.  A programmer who takes control of optimization could improve performance on the particular targeted platform, but compilers have improved to the point that overall performance on a variety of platforms is often best if one lets the compiler handle many optimization-related issues.

Comment: @DavidKessner: It's actually something of an awkward point to be, since there are still times when compilers definitely "need help", and since a compiler's efforts to optimize things may cause what would appear to be a minor design tweak to radically alter the generated code; that can be annoying in software, and I'd expect it could be annoying in hardware as well.  Still, there are definitely cases where smart logic compilers could be helpful if they were 'smart' enough.  For example...

Comment: @DavidKessner: Suppose one is trying to design a serial in/out device to accelerate 64xN multiplies.  Such a device could use a 64-bit accumulator with a 64-bit carry chain, or it could use 64 latches for the accumulator and 64 for saved carries, or 16 groups of five latches each representing a 4-bit value and saved carry, etc.  The optimal subdivision would depend greatly on the chip topology, and what's optimum for one chip would be vastly bloated on another.

Comment: @supercat Software compilers have had one huge trump card:  CPU speeds have vastly increased.  Sure, the compilers do optimize better but often (but not always) hand optimized assembler is still better.  Of course hardly anybody writes code in assembly these days because the CPU speed is fast enough that it doesn't make economic sense.  FPGA's are not quite there yet, but we can dream!  One day we'll look at this topic as antiquated, much like manual loop unrolling in software is antiquated.

Comment: @DavidKessner: Assembly code which is hand-optimized for a particular machine will be better than compiled code, but if a new machine comes out and compiler writers produce a code generator for it, high-level code written for the earlier machine will often work better on the new one (after a recompile) than would the hand-generated assembly code.  Further, the improvements in just-in-time compiler technology means the "recompile" will happen automatically if one tries to run the code on the new machine.

Comment: @DavidKessner: Sorry to be a pain, but you make lots of assertions about how synthesis tools *might* produce a poor result, but no evidence.  My question is about *measurable* benefits.  (And I did mean `count-1`, as that infers the carry/borrow bit in much the same way as your first example)

Comment: @MartinThompson, There may be a miscommunication here. What he is attempting to tell you. It is not that he is not sure that they exist, it is that you cannot bank on any of those features. It **may** happen based on the toolchain you choose. This means he is telling you that you are having to deal with a fact that you really cannot know unless you use your compiler. This is very common in many different languages, try doing a divide by 64 on a random microcontroller and timing it. You will find we cannot tell you how functional it is unless we know your compiler and toolchain.

Comment: @Kortuk: I see what he and you are saying - I've "pushed on the rope" of the tools plenty of times myself.  I guess what I'm trying to drag to the forefront is whether these kinds of "really low-level optimisation" tricks are worth playing anymore.   Much as C programmers don't write constant multiplies as sums-of-shifts anymore, now that compilers do it for you. I'm hoping someone might have some hard data... but if not, I'll try and generate some.

Comment: @MartinThompson  I am most familiar with a Xilinx Spartan-3/6 and the XST compiler.  For this combination these optimization techniques are worth it.  With a different FPGA and/or compiler your mileage may vary.  It is worth it to do the experiment yourself, if only to gain the knowledge.  I haven't done that experiment in a while, and unfortunately I don't have time to do it again.  Otherwise I would post my data.

Comment: @DavidKessner you have certainly provided a THOROUGH and well reasoned answer, you've got my +1. I have to ask though... why are you worried about optimization throughout the design? Wouldn't it be better to focus your efforts on the areas of code that require it or to focus on SLVs for interface points (entity ports) for compatibility? I know that in most of my designs I don't particularly care that LUT use is minimized, as long as it meets timing and fits the part. If I have particularly tight constraints I'd certainly be more conscious of optimal design, but not as a general rule.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith A lot of what I do goes into volume production where cost is an issue. Optimizing the design so it fits into a smaller or slower FPGA makes economic sense. Also, a lot of my code is in the form of core libraries which then get used and reused in dozens of other FPGA's. While size might not be an issue for that first FPGA, it could for the FPGAs that follow.  But keep in mind that logic that is small and efficient is generally also the quickest-- they do go hand in hand.

Comment: @DavidKessner: "Simply put, if you declare a signal of type int, or have to specify a range for an integer then you're probably doing something wrong."  - I think that's a matter of opinion! Integer signals have plenty of useful uses and I also do dense low-cost designs.  BTW. I added an answer with some synthesis LUT count/fmax figures in.

Comment: I am a bit surpriced by the number of up-votes on this answer. @bit_vector@ is certainly the correct abstraction level for modeling and optimizing micro-architectures, but a general recommendation agains "high-level" types such as @integer@ for signals and port is something I find strange. I've seen enough convoluted and unreadable code due to the lack of abstraction to know the value these features provide, and would be very sad if I had to leave them behind.

Comment: @trondd  The up-votes are because I answered the question, "when is it neater to use vectors vs. integer?"  If the question were about the correct time to use integer types then you might get an answer more favorable to your bias.  You are more than welcome to add your own answer to this question.

Comment: You certainly have a valid point regarding optimized micro-achitectures, but the reason I question it is because the example you provide is shown by Martin Thompson to have equivalent implementations using both alternatives.

I also think the general recommendation against high-level types is plain wrong. Proper level of abstraction would be a good general advice: Bit level modeling at one level, higher-level types. Readability also matters a lot, and the divide by 2**n example from Martin is an excellent example where vectors are preferred.

Comment: @trondd Once upon a time, people wrote software in assembly.  It was the right tool at the right time, because compilers were not generating efficient enough code and our CPUs were limited.  In many ways this has changed and assembly code is used much less these days.  The same is true for programmable logic, but we're just now starting to get out of the dark ages.  In principle I agree with you, but I also have a job to do and can't afford Synplify Pro at US$12k/year.  I also have to write code that is efficient on many tool chains.  Someday your utopia will exist, but that isn't today.

Comment: @david Excellent remarks. It's true we're still in the medieval age compared to software development in many ways, but from my experience with Quartus integrated synthesis and Synplify I don't think things are that bad. They are quite capable of handling lots of things like register retiming and other optimizations that improves performance while maintaining readability. I doubt the majority is targeting several toolchains and devices, but for your case I understand the requirement for the least common denominator :-).

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to try both, and then look at the synthesis, map, and place-and-route reports.  These reports will tell you exactly how many LUTs each approach is consuming, they will also tell you the maximum speed at which the logic can operate.

I agree with David Kessner that you're at the mercy of your toolchain, and there is no "right" answer.  Synthesis is black magic and the best way to know what happened is to carefully and thoroughly read the reports that are produced.  Xilinx tools even allow you to see inside the FPGA, right down to how each LUT is programmed, how the carry chain is connected, how the switch fabric connects all the LUTs, etc.

For another dramatic example of Mr. Kessner's approach, imagine that you want to have multiple clock frequencies at 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc.  You could use an integer that constantly counts up every cycle, and then have multiple comparators against that integer value, with each comparator output forming a different clock division.  Depending on the number of comparators, the fanout could become unreasonably large and start consuming extra LUTs just for buffering.  The SLV approach would just take each individual bit of the vector as an output.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious reason is that signed and unsigned allow larger values than the 32 bit integer. That is a flaw in the VHDL language design, which is not essential. A new version of VHDL could fix that, requiring integer values to support arbitrary size (akin to Java's BigInt).

Other than that, I'm very interested to hear about benchmarks that perform differently for integer as compared to vectors.

BTW, Jan Decaluwe wrote a nice essay on this: [These Ints are made for Countin'](http://jandecaluwe.com/hdldesign/counting.html)

Comment: Thanks Philippe (although that's not a "better through access to the internal representation" application, which is what I'm really after...)

Comment: That essay is nice, but completely ignores the underlying implementation and resulting logic speed and size.  I agree with most of what Decaluwe says, but he doesn't say anything about the results of synthesis.  Sometimes the results of synthesis don't matter, and sometimes they do.  So it's a judgement call.

Comment: @David, I agree that Jan does not go into full detail on how synthesis tools react to integers.
But, no it is not a judgment call. You can measure the synthesis results and determine the results of your given synthesis tool. I think the OP meant his question as a challenge for us to produce code fragments and synthesis results that demonstrate a difference (if any) in performance.

Comment: @Philippe  No, I meant that it's a judgement call on if you care at all about the synthesis results at all.  Not that the synthesis results themselves are a judgement call.

Comment: @DavidKessner OK. I misunderstood.